# Add automatic classes to each <li>

Tags: php, class, render

I have a list of < li >'s but without classes, I want to make for EACH < li > a different class.. something like this

< li class="1" >
< li class="2" >
< li class="3" >

Here is the code that I have:

```
<ul id="tralila">
    <?php
    foreach($lists as $key=>$region)
    { 
    ?>
        <li>
            <?php  $regionLink =  "index.php?option=$option&Itemid=$listitemid&task=regions.region&rid=$region->id";
                   echo '<a href="'.$regionLink.'">'.$region->title.'</a>';?> 
        </li>
    <?php
        $location = $key+1;
    } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
<ul id="tralila">
    <?php
    $class_name = 0;
    foreach($lists as $key=>$region)
    { 

    ?>
        <li class="<?=++$class_name;?>">
            <?php  $regionLink =  "index.php?option=$option&Itemid=$listitemid&task=regions.region&rid=$region->id";
                   echo '<a href="'.$regionLink.'">'.$region->title.'</a>';?> 
        </li>
    <?php
        $location = $key+1;
    } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @AlexandruVlas No its not. This will create an invalid class name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: <li class="text<?=++$class_name;?>">

Comment: Thank you everybody. 
I tried nosbor's code and it worked like a charm.

Thank you all!!
Cheers
Alex

Comment: @AlexandruVlas: There are better and earlier-posted answers to choose from. My biggest gripe about this one is using `<?=` for an `echo` shortcut, which is not recommended.

Comment: but what can the "<?=" do bad to my site? because I see that it works ok .... what would you recommend ? Thanks

Comment: @AlexandruVlas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: Thanks. I understood now. Thanks everybody !

Comment: @EvanMulawski: Come on.  Be constructive; edit and fix, don't comment and diss.  Hey, that's not bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach($lists as $key=>$region)
{ 
?>
    <li class="<?php echo "className$i"; ?>">
        <?php  $regionLink =  "index.php?option=$option&Itemid=$listitemid&task=regions.region&rid=$region->id";
               echo '<a href="'.$regionLink.'">'.$region->title.'</a>';?> 
    </li>
<?php
    $location = $key+1;
    $i++;
} ?>
```

Or, instead, you could use the `$key` from your `foreach` instead of creating, and incrementing, a counter variable.

Comment: Thank you everybody. 
I tried nosbor's code and it worked like a charm.

Thank you all!!
Cheers
Alex

Comment: +1 for a sensible answer by fixing the proposed invalid class names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Answer (score 0):

So this is how you would do it using the key from `$lists`. Note I have added a prefix of `li-` as classes cannot start with a digit. See: [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)

```
<ul id="tralila">
    <?php
    foreach($lists as $key=>$region)
    { 
    ?>
        <li class="<?php echo 'li-' . htmlentities($key); ?>">
            <?php  $regionLink =  "index.php?option=$option&Itemid=$listitemid&task=regions.region&rid=$region->id";
                   echo '<a href="'.$regionLink.'">'.$region->title.'</a>';?> 
        </li>
    <?php
        $location = $key+1;
    } ?>
</ul>
```

As all of the classes are unique I would use IDs instead of a class though.

Comment: Thank you everybody. 
I tried nosbor's code and it worked like a charm.

Thank you all!!
Cheers
Alex

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter could explain the problem with this code so I can learn from their greater wisdom on the topic?